# Are there any languages or cultures that have genderless given names?

Tags: gender, names, list-of-languages

In the U.S. where I live it is possible to be right almost all of the time when guessing the sex of a person from his or her given name: Ronald, George (Sand and Elliot notwithstanding), William, Michael (Learned notwithstanding), Warren and Chuck are all men's names, while Emily, Christine, Jasmine, Nancy and Camille are obviously female. Some nicknames go both ways (Chris, Sandy, Sam, etc.) but the full names are generally obviously on one side or the other.

In German, generally nobody thinks Karlheinz is female or Gisele is male. Cf. Spanish (Juan, Juanita, etc.), French (Michel, Michelle) and so on. Even in Latin, it was possible to tell Julia and Julius apart by letters alone.

Some languages have markers to indicate gender (see [this Linguistics.SE question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1634/171). That question discusses PIE affixes, but the scope is even broader. For example, in Japanese, *-o* or *-ro* endings indicate male names, while *-ko* and *-e* indicate female names. Note that my question is *not* limited to the scope of that question.

I don't know all the languages that have ever existed in the world, obviously, but all of the ones I have had contact with make a more-or-less clear gender distinction with given names. Are there or have there ever been languages that didn't make this distinction?

Comment: Most names whose etymologies I know probably come from stems praising or describing the bearer. Since men and women are often praised and described differently, I would expect most language to have a considerable number of sex-bound given names. Note that Julia and Julius were not given names but family names, although your hypothesis may still hold for Latin. However, I don't think the Romans had many given names (perhaps none) where the same stem was used for a male and a female name. There is Marcus, but no Marca; and I believe women normally used the family name, not a given name.

Comment: However, I don't know much about plebeian given names. They must have had them.

Comment: There was a long discussion of this question on the LINGTYP mailing list some time ago, initiated by Professor Newmeyer. http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1208B&L=LINGTYP&F=&S=&P=965

Comment: While it also has names that are gender-specific, Japanese also has a good number of gender-neutral names (though they may be written with different kanji depending on gender).

Comment: Robusto, are you asking for languages that *also* have genderless given names, or *only* those names? Because in the first case, I know an example.

Comment: @Alenanno: I gave cases where gender is ambiguous. We also see some names, in America at least, that are made-up and carry no gender connotation (*River*, for example). I'm happy to hear what you have, but I really want to know about languages that make *no* distinction in gender — preferably not deliberately, but because it does not occur to the speakers to do so.

Comment: @Cerberus  Romans could use numerals-derived names for women, such as Secunda etc. But they also were sex-dependent

Comment: I'd say this might actually be quite a western-centric phenomenon and I'm not sure whether it's even mainstream in the world. Maybe more cultures give genderless names than not. It's just that when names are transcribed into western alphabets, western people won't be able to tell what they originally meant anyways, so they suppose that gender-specific names as such in their culture are the norm.

Comment: Also your example about Japanese is not really correct. See detailed explanation in my answer below.

Comment: @Cerberus: Marcus => Marcia?

Comment: @Rob Hail thee! That is a very interesting example. I had to look it up, and it appears *Marcia* is the female version of *Marcius*, used for women of the *gens Marcia*. So I think it is like *Julia*, which is from *Julius*, not *Julus* (the son of Aeneas).

Comment: The wikipedia page on unisex names contains a list of languages, examples and contexts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the Punjabi language. Well spoken by the Sikh culture. Many, many, many names are genderless. Only in modern times (past 50–100 years) have there started to exist some names that are more associated with one gender than the other.

This website, [Baby Names World](http://babynamesworld.parentsconnect.com/category-sikh-names.html), would fool you into thinking that's not the case. But I know many people whose names are registered there as female who are male and vice versa.

A Google search for "Sikh names" usually leads to results that mention how their names are genderless. The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikh_names) says, "Given names are not in general associated with a particular gender". If gender is to be indicated people say both their first/given name as well as their middle/last name.

Doing a Google search for the *exact phrase of your question* led to this [Yahoo question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aK1wVqOwCkakJ%3aanswers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080923085111AAstKzu%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) from 2008 that states:

> In Chinese it is normal for names to be for both boys and girls, because there isn't a specific group of "words" that are only used as names, where you can only choose your name from this group like in the Western World, eg. "Anna" isn't a word, but is something that can only be used as a (girl's) name. In Chinese you can use any word or words (max. 2 characters) you like as your name, provided it sounds good and you find it meaningful, just like the names of Native Americans commented above.
>
> Of course, names that are flowers are generally girls' names and names with "strength" and such themes are generally boys' names, but other words are mostly neutral. In earlier times there was stronger distinction between genders, but today, where "flower" names and such are pretty much out of the fashion, you would not immediately know the gender of the person when you read their name. Korean names are also similar in this way.

Continuing on my Google search, I found this extremely [lovely article](http://www.slate.com/articles/double_x/doublex/2012/04/hen_sweden_s_new_gender_neutral_pronoun_causes_controversy_.html) about how Sweden is trying to pass legislature on allowing parents to give their child *any* name (like *Jack* or *Lisa*), saying that names should not be tied to gender.

So all in all there is at least three distinct groups of languages/cultures (and many more, I'm sure, are tied to these three groups) that either have genderless given names or are advocating for such a goal.

Comment: You mean Sweden *doesn't* already permit cross-naming? I wonder if Alice Cooper can even get into the country then.

Comment: But for Sikh names, going by the WP page, the gender is evident from the surname. I don't believe that this is the case with Chinese names. Interesting stuff :)

Comment: that is correct. middle/surname. But the question was specifically for given names ;) unless it was edited... O_o

Answer (score 14):

Vietnamese names, like Chinese, have **no specific name set**. So the choice depends on the parents or the person who gives the name. They can choose **any syllable** they like to combine into the name. But of course there's a set of words that are much more commonly appear in names because they are "more beautiful" words. However Vietnamese name have no limit in number of syllables like Chinese names, although most will have 3-4 syllables. Like Koreans, Vietnamese names are mainly Sino-Vietnamese but there are also pure-Vietnamese names

There's **no restriction in gender** of the name either, but most will have some *bias* in gender.

For example when hearing the names such as *Mai* 梅, *Lan* 蘭, *Thúy* 翠/脆, *Vân* 雲... you can guess that they are women's names most of the time because they describe things such as flowers and birds... They feel more "feminine" and "soft", albeit there are men who were given those names too.

On the other hand names such as *Trung* 中/忠, *Hùng* 熊/雄, *Dũng* 勇, *Mạnh* 孟... would have 95% chance to be a man's name because they express vigor, strength...

Most other names are more neutral in gender. The possibility for *Phúc* 福, *Tú* 繡/秀, *Phương* 方/芳... to be a man's/woman's name might be 50/50 whereas *Thanh* 清/聲/青, *Hà* 何/河... perhaps are a bit more "womanly" because in 55-60% of the cases they are a woman's name

In the past women often had *Thị* 是 and men usually had *Văn* 文 as the middle name so you could infer sex information from that. But nowadays those aren't favorable any more, replaced with more "fashionable" middle names, and there are many people who don't have middle names, so occasionally you can't get gender hints from that anymore. But when going along with an appropriate given name, sometimes it will reverse the gender bias or make the bias stronger. For example *Anh* 英 and *Thanh* 青 are neutral names, but with *Vân* 雲 as middle name then *Vân Anh* 雲英 or *Vân Thanh* 雲青 would be a woman's name. Or *Dương* 陽 is more or less a man's name, but *Thùy Dương* 垂陽 would be a woman's name

Note that the percentages are only from the sense of a Vietnamese person, not any specific statistics so it may not reflect exactly the actual number.

Comment: I’ve read that many Vietnamese given names are derived from Chinese.  If so, I wonder if the fact that they are written in quốc ngữ rather than with characters adds a degree of ambiguity gender-wise.

Comment: I do not see how writing the names in Chinese characters would make them any less ambiguous.

Comment: But thank you, Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, for a very instructive answer.

Comment: You should mention in this scheme that *last* name is the given name perhaps. By the time one reads this comment, they will likely have figured out already. @fdb the dotted squares in 梅 are tits, similarly derived as the less obvious 文 "female", if I remember correctly. 陽 has a horse in bottom right (corresponding to *ng* in duong?), IMHO that's neutral (Ger. neuter *das Pferd*) but depends on culture. 中 is a dragon. 英 looks like a human with proper tits--or big eyes (OwO)--and Anh reminds of *Anna, Ane, Amma, etc.* "Mum". The rest I don't know yet. I see wiener, elephant, king/sky ...

Comment: In fact, 陽 does in Chinese mean Penis, and the male part of yin and yang, the first part of it is silent and supposed to mean "hill", the right part including the horse is phonetic and derives from a word *bright, sunshine*. I'm probably confusing a bunch. Go look it up yourself! BTW, are the different alternative spellings gender specific? In 清/聲/青, we see a kings cross, a female, and in the bottom, I guess, an elephant. The female looks like it's wearing a baseball cap, haha, I'm joking. In 何/河 only the silent parts differ, the left one reads "man, human", is why I ask.

Answer (score 5):

Tibetan and Bhutanese names are genderless. I'm not a native of those countries, but travelled to both, and found the same names used for both men and women. I've had it confirmed as much as well that the names there do not confer gender, ie they're used interchangeably between genders. Worth doing some more investigation to be sure. Cheers.

Comment: The Bhutanese language is actually called Dzongkha if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

In Yoruba (and many other languages spoken in Africa) there is no gender distinction for personal names. Lukumi, a decendent form of Yoruba, has inherited the same feature.

In some IU languages, there is no gender distinction for some specific names or their forms. Here is a list of French [unisex names](http://french.about.com/od/culture/a/frenchnames_4.htm/)

Comment: What are "IU languages"?

Comment: I'm guessing Indo-Uropean. ;-)

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 3):

Turkish has many genderless names e.g Deniz "sea", Devrim "revolution", Yuksel "raise", Özgur "free", Ilhan "ruler", Ismet "ethical, honest", Fikret "idea, opinion", Ömür "lifetime".

I am sure there are more, but I am not aware of those. Some Turkish member can provide more examples. I guess the Turkic names are the ones that are usually genderless, unless they refer to something that is specifically female or male e.g Asena "she wolf".

Comment: So male as well as female infants are equally likely to receive any of those names?

Comment: @Robusto >> Statistically yes. However, unequal distribution (30-70%) is still genderless, as a significant percentage of the parents see the name fitting to any gender. Especially, if the name is neuter (e.g. as "hope" is in some languages) then there is no reason why to regard it as gender specific. There are examples though in Turkic languages where a "male word" becomes a female name e.g. Suna is a "male drake", but the name is given to girls.

Comment: Given the confusion an apparent uncertainty around Turkish etymology, I have to wonder how many of these are true homophones converged from separate gender specific names. Eg. for *Suna* compare English *sun*, *little sunshine*. I'm just guessing, you get the idea. Names have a tendency for glorious reinterpretation, after all.

Answer (score 3):

In Mongolian, there are a number of strictly neutral names, e.g. names derived from planets, names derived from rivers, or "bad" names or "non-names"*. There are also names that have a strong tendency towards a certain gender, e.g. anything with "strong" or "steel" or "hero" in it for males, or "light" and "chrystal" for females. And there are names that are somewhat in-between

It also used to be common to give boys female names, and even dress them up as girls when they are small, if previously a boy had died in the family. This was/is done in order to confuse evil spirits - but this is not really related to names having an associated gender or not.

---

*(bad names or "non-names" were often given if another child had died in the family, in order to make the new child less of a target for evil spirits. Typical examples are "Nameless", "Not this one", "Ugly" and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all Indonesian names are gender-specific. Usually, you can tell their gender by endings. Names that end in -a, -Vti/-Nti (preceded by a vowel or nasal), -e, -iN, and -ah are usually feminine. Names that end in -o, -u, -di, -C (consonants; except -h), and -CCi (except -rni, -tri, etc.) are usually masculine. Exceptions are Yoga, Dirga, Rama, Fitrah, and Sakti (all are masculine); and Lulu, Betik, and Daniar (all are feminine).
Some are genderless though, such as Riski, Andika, Aditya, etc. But you can determine their gender by their nicknames. A Riski is usually a male if it is called Iki, but it is usually a female if it is called Kiki. Andika can be male (Dika, Andi) or female (Ika). Aditya can also be male (Adit) or female (Tia or Tya).

But in Indonesia, you can find some names that is one masculine in a part but feminine in another part, or vice versa. Or one gender in a part but genderless in another part. Nana is usually male in Sunda (mainly in West Java), but female elsewhere. Nur is genderless in Java, but feminine elsewhere (also in Maluku Nur- part is almost always not separated).

Answer (score -2):

I'd say this (names indicating gender) might actually be quite a **western-centric phenomenon** and I'm not sure whether it's even mainstream in the world. It's totally possible that more cultures give genderless names than not. It's just that when names are transcribed into western alphabets, western people won't be able to tell what they originally meant anyways, so they still suppose that gender-specific names as such in their culture are the norm.

Coming to think of it, it's actually very weird for us Chinese to see that in western societies 1. there are strict distinctions between male names and female names which are not to be easily violated by social norms and 2. once a female gets married to a male, she changes her surname. Such things never happen in China. And also, your example about Japanese is largely incorrect. While the suffixes you listed are indeed common male/female names, there are also a whole lot of names which are neutral in the same manner as in Chinese. I'd say actually in modern Japan the later case might even be much more than the previous case. One funny historical fact is that during the sengoku period, there was a female lord named 井伊直虎(Ii Naotora), with 直虎 being a totally male and "strong" name (虎 is "tiger"). Well I guess the situation of this question(so many upvotes) reflects the fact that the majority of people here on SE are still westerners then :P

Comment: Lots of non-Western cultures have separate names for boys and girls, for example Arabic, Persian, most Indian cultures, most African cultures, etc. etc.

Comment: @fdb As you can see, many East Asian cultures don't have such a convention, and they constitute an important part of the world population. Also, although there might traditionally have been names more commonly given to male/female in the cultures you mentioned, unisex names have also been constantly present throughout the history. I'd suppose the fact that western Christian societies stick to gender-specific names to such an extent that they encode the practice into laws is not something common worldwide(I might be wrong of course), and this is what I want to express; I mean no offense.

Comment: @Robusto I know. I guess I mostly just wanted to express my opinions on the question (and the way it's paraphrased). Maybe I should have written most of my points into various comments instead of writing it up into an answer here.

Comment: Please update your answer and remove all mention of cultures other than the far-east ones. As many other people have pointed out, you have been quite inaccurate about them. Instead, write about the cultures you *do* know well.